# swapping rows in pylab matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to swap 2 rows of pylab matrix a. However, when is use a[0],a[1] = a[1],a[0] it does not work:

```
>>> from pylab import *
>>> a = matrix([ [1.,2.] , [3.,4.] ])
>>> print a
  [[ 1.  2.]
  [ 3.  4.]]
>>> a[0],a[1] = a[1],a[0]
>>> print a
  [[ 3.  4.]
  [ 3.  4.]]
```

How can I swap the rows properly?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`a[[1,0]]` gets the 2nd row and then the 1st row, if your want to write back:

```
In [842]: a[[0,1]]=a[[1,0]]

In [843]: a
Out[843]: 
matrix([[ 3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  2.]])
```

or make it a function:

```
In [848]: def swapMatRow(mat, r1, r2):
     ...:     mat[[r1,r2]]=mat[[r2, r1]]
     ...:     

In [850]: a = np.matrix([ [1.,2.] , [3.,4.] ])

In [851]: swapMatRow(a, 0, 1)

In [852]: a
Out[852]: 
matrix([[ 3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  2.]])
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @user1767774 Use: `a[0:2,] = a[[1, 0]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Indexing/slicing returns a view of the the array, to swap items you can use a temporary variable that contains copy of one of the rows:

```
>>> a = np.matrix([ [1.,2.] , [3.,4.] ])
>>> temp = a[0].copy()  #New copy of a[0]
>>> a[0], a[1] = a[1], temp
>>> a
matrix([[ 3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  2.]])
```

A simple `a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]` didn't work because instead of returning the items itself, NumPy returns a view of the array items. So, as soon as the first assignment `a[0] <-- a[1]` is done, we've actually changed the other item `a[0]`(on the RHS) as well, so the next assignment `a[1] <-- a[0]` simply results in copying the new `a[0]` to `a[1]`, hence we get `a[1]` repeated twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could also reverse the rows:

```
In [125]: a = a[::-1]

In [126]: a
Out[126]: 
matrix([[ 3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  2.]])
```